# Strong deformation retraction between CW-complexes, Brown theorem proof

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, retraction, representable-functor

I am currently reading Lemma 9.11 on Switzer, in the chapter dedicated to Brown representability theorem. However I am stuck on a few points of the proof.

Let $F$ a contravariant functor from pointed CW complexes up to homotopy to pointed sets. Let $Y$ be a pointed CW complex, $u \in F(Y)$ and $(X, A, x_0)$ a CW-pair. Let $g : (A, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ a cellular map. Let $T =( I^{+} \wedge A) \vee X \vee Y$, by identifying $[0,a] \in I^{+} \wedge A$ with $a \in X$ and $[1,a] \in I^{+} \wedge A$ with $g(a) \in Y$. Let $A_1 =( [0, 1/2]^{+} \wedge A) \cup X$ and $A_2 =( [1/2, 1]^{+} \wedge A) \cup Y$. Now $A_1 \cup A_2 = T, A_1 \cap A_2$ is isomorphic to $A$. Until this point it is all clear. What I don’t understand is the following:

There is a strong deformation retraction $f: A_1 \to X$ and $Y$ is a strong deformation retract of $A_2$. Thus there are $\bar{v} \in F(A_1)$ with $\bar{v}|_{X} = v$ and a $\bar{u} \in F(A_2)$ with $\bar{u}|_{Y}= u$. Why is that?

Comment: Probably $T = A_1 {\color{red} \cup} A_2$, not the intersection? Can you draw a picture of $T, A_1, A_2$? Also, who is $v$ (an element of $FX$?), and what about $(-)|_X, (-)|_Y$? An element $\bar u$ such that $Fr(\bar u)=u\in FY$, for some $r : A_2\to Y$ comes form the fact that $Y$ is a sdr of $A_2$, so you get a surjective map $FA_2 \to FY$ (every functor sends retracts to retracts, which are [absolute colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/absolute+colimit)).

Comment: I managed to do̶w̶n̶l̶  find a copy of Switzer and the element $u$ isn't just any element, it is a *universal* element; this means first of all that $F$ is **contra** variant (as it must be, if in the end it will represent cohomology), and that there is an isomorphism $\pi_n(Y)\cong F(S^n)$ for all $n\ge 0$, induced by evaluating on $u$ as per def. 9.6; also, $F$ is probably required to satisfy some form of cohomology axiom (preserving coproducts and Mayer-Vietoris sequences)? The above isomorphism makes sense only when $F(S^n)$ is naturally a(n abelian) group...

Comment: You are indeed totally right, I miswrote a few crucial points, I am editing right now

Comment: Could you please expand a little bit more on the sdr story?

Comment: Every def of strong deformation retract turns out to be quite a mouthful, allow me not to recall it completely: a sdr of a space $Q$ onto $Z$ is a surective map $r : Q \to Z$, left inverse to the inclusion $i : Z \subset Q$, with additional properties. Since a functor preserves compositions and identities, it sends the equation $r\circ i=1_Z$ to the equation $Fr\circ Fi = 1_{FX}$. This means that $Fr$ is a split epimorphism, thus a surjective function (and dually, $Fi$ is a split mono, hence injective). (Note that contravariance of $F$ means that you have to reverse the roles of $Fr$ and $Fi$)

Comment: Switzer is a little bit of a mouthful too (especially given its age); you can find the same proof of Brown's theorem in Strom, "Modern classical homotopy theory", pp. 489-495; it's the very same idea and nomenclature, but the categorical lingo is a bit more up to date ("$n$-universal elements"?!)

Comment: Ok thanks, that’s clear. Now it is only left to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are strong deformation retracts

Comment: I’ll surely give a look to Strom. Eventually I figured Switzer’s definition of $n$-universal elements is totally functional to ease the proof of Brown theorem on its own, but I figured it is indeed quite unusual. However I still would love to unlock all the secrets of those sd retracts...

Comment: @Fosco I was rereading the comments and I realised I overlooked quite an interesting point: why were you saying that it makes sense for a functor to be contravariant in the context of Brown theorem?

Comment: The superficial and one-line answer is that cohomology theories are contravariant functors, and there's no such thing as a BRT for homology theories. The reason *why* there is no such BRT is probaby the second thing too large to expand for this narrow margin... a form of BRT says that a functor $F : \mathcal C^{op} \to Set$ defined on a category generated by a [strong separating family](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator) made of cogroup objects is representable if and only if it preserves products and it is a Mayer-Vietoris functor.

Comment: Now, a putative BRT for homology shall look like this: $F : \mathcal C \to Set$ is representable if and only if [dual of everything above]. Unfortunately, coseparating families of objects in categories generated by limits are ill-behaved and they do not lend themselves to the techniques proper of the proof of BRT that I know; such a proof builds an object $X_F$ such that $\hom(E,X_F)\cong FE$ (naturally in $E$), as a sequential colimit $X_\infty\cong \varinjlim (X_0\to X_1 \to X_2\to \dots)$, and uses _a lot_ the joint conservativity of the separating family mentioned above.

Comment: There are of course topological reasons for the absence of a BRT for homology, but I feel I'm writing too much already; I guess people in algebraic topology internalized the fact that covariant BRT is just "not a thing", and the common habit of geometers to consider contravariant functors as "the right thing" did the rest. A similar phenomenon appears elsewhere: sheaves (=contravariant) are a thing; cosheaves, on the contrary, are the Rosemary's baby of algebraic geometry.

Comment: That was great insight, thank you

Comment: Let me end with the punchline: by Yoneda lemma, a presheaf $F : \mathcal C^{op} \to Set$ [is representable if and only if its category of elements has a terminal object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+element), and all the pain one has to undergo to prove BRT is meant to *construct* such object. This is attained using the assumption that $\mathcal C$ is generated under colimits by the separating family above. Also, [this](https://i.postimg.cc/s2kbk6qC/image.png) is how Strom tries to convince you that there is no conceptual reason for homology to exist.

Comment: Are you implying that a classifying space is a terminal object?

Comment: So it seems, but I wouldn't judge this as a particularly deep insight; the reason why representability of $F$ amounts to the existence of a terminal object $T$ in $Elts(F)$ is that terminality in $Elts(F)$ is, word-by-word, the request that there exists a natural isomorphism $F(-) \cong hom(-,T)$.

Comment: Oh, and I was wrong: it's false that "there's no such thing as BRT for homology"; with an additional assumption on the homology theories (each $h_n$ commutes with directed colimits), homology theories still correspond to spectra.

Comment: More precisely, to each prespectrum $\{K^i\}$ you can associate a homology theory $$ h_n(X) := \varinjlim_{i\in\mathbb N} \pi_{n+i}(K^i\land X)$$ This happens for example for the sphere spectrum (you obtain stable homotopy) or for $K(G,n)$'s (you obtain classical singular homology). You need the additional assumption  to go the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your space $T$ is nothing else than the reduced [double mapping cylinder](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Double_mapping_cylinder) of the maps $\iota : A \hookrightarrow X$ and $g : A \to Y$. To see that, note that $I^+ \wedge A = (I \times
A)/(I \times \{a_0\})$.

The subspaces $A_1$ and $A_2$ of $T$ are copies of the reduced mapping cylinders of $\iota$ and of $g$. Thus you get the usual strong deformation retractions $f : A_1 \to X$ and $r : A_2 \to Y$. Hence the inclusions $i_1 : X \to A_1$ and $i_2 : Y \to A_2$ are homotopy equivalences and induce bijections $i_1^* : F(A_1)  \to F(X)$ and $i_2^* : F(A_2)  \to F(Y)$.

Now consider $v \in F(X)$ and $u \in F(Y)$.

1. Let $\bar v = (i_1^*)^{-1}(v) \in F(A_1)$. Then by definition $\bar v  \mid_X = i^*_1(\bar v) = i^*_1( (i_1^*)^{-1}(v)) = v$.
2. Let $\bar u = (i_2^*)^{-1}(u) \in F(A_2)$. Then $\bar u  \mid_Y = u$.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, I was rereading your answer: could you please give me reference for the implication “$i_1$ is an homotopy equivalence, therefore $i_1^{*}$ is a bijection?” Is it because homotopy equivalences are isomorphisms in the domain category, therefore they are preserved by $F$? In that case, is $F$ fully faithful?

Comment: @cip Yes, each functor preserves isomorphisms; it is irrelevant whether $F$ is full or faithful. Also note that the $i_k$ are *no* isomorphisms, but induce isomorphisms in the homotopy category on which $F$ lives.

Comment: Yes, I realised I had not specified in my question that the domain category is that of pointed CW-complexes up to homotopy. Thanks a lot! :)